# How to count how many times a value exist and calculate percentage in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with 35 columns with values 0 and 1. Each column represents a question and the values 0 and 1 represents who answered and who doesn't. Something like this:

```
 ID   NAME   Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4 ... QN

  1   Cesar   0  1  1  0  ... 1
  2   Daniel  1  0  0  1  ... 0
  3   Albert  0  1  0  1  ... 1
```

I need to know **what questions were the less answered**. I was thinking about a loop that runs over the colums and count the quantity of zeros, so the columns that has more ceros are the less answered. However i don't know how to do that. I need some help. I have 2 weeks working with R.

Comment: try `which.min(colSums(your.data.frame[, -c(1,2)]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `colSums` as mentioned by @Jilber Urbina. `colSums` would return the count of number of people who answered the question (count of 1's), if you `sort` the results it would sort the data in increasing order meaning the 1st value is the question which is least answered.

```
cols <- grep('Q\\d+', names(df))
sort(colSums(df[cols]))
```